# Why is this job link broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I frequently see an iOS job at Coolblue listed in the little jobs ad thingy. The link takes me to:

http://clc.stackoverflow.com/ct?an=Y2NieCBwbGpp5WUPhtrv_AysjAx8p5hYWRgYGdgZgIDljD0zQ42mvtzHM2_sWcHijHJAgoUTJMkHJPiZgMQqR2aGrnl276Uz4Kps4Kr-gVQxAglpRSaGrpS6Tv-MdzjMYgYSh4FmRVs1eCbx3IWp4gKpApnAwgAzS0se7DQ2pgA_H1aQ9eyMIBbICjZmEAtkDAOjBpAVMWniGj-mMzUrvwEA&at=0&tz=3&ti=213418&tr=large-sidebar-orange-looking

Which redirects to a "job not found" page. However, if I look up Coolblue in the jobs section, I can see the iOS job listed and I can visit the link from there. That one takes me to:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/113418/senior-ios-developer-coolblue

I don't know how the internal linking happens so I can't compare if they are actually the same job, but it seems to me they are. Why does one work, but the other not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in the synchronization between jobs and ads where ID's were getting mixed up. *Really* sorry about that, and thanks for the heads up.