# SO Android App broken links in JOBS (Careers)

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, android-app

I have a problem in SO android app.

In dashboard under the Hot Question there are SO Careers announcement when I click to link get to "http://clc.stackoverflow.com/" but in body write "**Not Found**"

> [image]

Comment: seems to have happened before: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322822/why-is-this-job-link-broken

Comment: Right i think still not fixed

Comment: Meh, it just happened again. probably a job that failed to complete within the time-limits.

Comment: I've got a repro for it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working now. Sorry about that, and thank you very much for reporting it.